# Issue with new POJO Object

Tags: java, android, pojo

I just made my first POJO Class, which takes two Strings and one String array and combines them into one (for lack of a better term) package. Everything seemed to be working well until the very last part. Here is my code:

```
class dataPOJO extends Phone_Save {
String fName;
String cName;
String[] cText;

public dataPOJO() {
    fName = file_name;
    cName = cname;
    cText = ctext;

}

public String getName() {
    return cName;
}

public void setName(String cName) {
    this.cName = cName;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return fName;
}

public void setFileName(String fName) {
    this.fName = fName;
}

public String[] getRemainder() {
    return cText;
}

public void getRemainder(String[] cText) {
    this.cText = cText;
}

public String toString() {
    String savePackage = "File Name: " + getFileName() + "\n";
    savePackage += "CName: " + getName() + "\n";
    savePackage += getRemainder() + "\n";
    return savePackage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {


    dataPOJO combine = new dataPOJO();
    combine.setName(cName);
    combine.setFileName(fName);
    combine.setRemainder(cText);
    System.out.println(combine);
}
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot setName as any of the strings I referenced above. To me, it seems like I should be able to. And I can't put a default name in there like:

```
combine.setName("default name");
```

because the name comes from user input and is different every time. My question is how can I set the value of the String array below to the strings like cName referenced above?
Thanks! 
**Added code**

public class Phone_Save extends ActionBarActivity {

```
String[] ctext;
public int doc_id = 0;
String cname;
Button fileName;
Button loadText;
String file_name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_save);
    Intent save_intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = save_intent.getExtras();
    EditText file_name_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final TextView loaded_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loaded_text);
    file_name = file_name_edit.getText().toString();
    fileName = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fName);
    loadText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadText);


    if (bundle != null) {
        ctext = bundle.getStringArray("confirmed_text");
        cname = bundle.getString("confirmed_name");


    }

    fileName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new dataPOJO();



        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I can't understand the problem you're asking about.

Comment: I can't understand where your no-args constructor gets args.

Comment: Also, don't think of it as a POJO class. It's just a class, a perfectly normal class. The word "POJO" is only useful to distinguish it from particular other types of classes (like you might say "a normal mouse" in a discussion about gaming mice, but in most contexts you'd just say "a mouse")

Comment: @ElliottFrisch neither do I. I am totally new to the POJO class. But this is the reference I used to create my object:                         http://crunchify.com/create-simple-pojo-and-multiple-java-reflection-examples/

Comment: Can you provide the code for Phone_Save class?

Comment: @Sigismundus There you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `dataPOJO` should not be extending `Phone_Save`. There's nothing `dataPOJO` needs to do that depends on it being an `Activity` (at least based on what you've shown us). If you want to have that class to store those information in one place, that's fine; otherwise just store them in `Phone_Save` itself. Right now you appear to be trying to do both at once, which is confusing.

Second, calling `new dataPOJO()` in the OnClickListener allocates an object, then discards it since it is not being assigned to anything. It's also a completely different object and has no effect on this one.

Third, there's no use for that `main` method on Android, it will never be called (unless you call it yourself, which would be pointless anyway).

I would make dataPOJO its own class that doesn't extend anything and get rid of the no-arg constructor (or leave it but remove the code that's in there). In your `Phone_Save`'s `onCreate` method, you can just make a dataPOJO and hang onto it.

```
public class DataPojo {
    String fName;
    String cName;
    String[] cText;

    public dataPOJO() {}

    /* all the other stuff */
}

public class Phone_Save extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DataPojo dataPojo;
    // other members

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dataPojo = new DataPojo();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        dataPojo.setName(intent.getStringExtra("confirmed_name"));
        dataPojo.setRemainder(intent.getStringExtra("confirmed_text"));

        // other stuff...
    }
}
```